# Error in Prestige$type : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, closures

I genuinely do not understand what this means or how to fix the problem.

This is the code  I did before I received the error:

```r
library(car)
head(Prestige)
?Prestige
Prestige<-na.omit

table(Prestige$type)
###Error in Prestige$type : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable###

levels(Prestige$type)
###Error in Prestige$type : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable###
```

And I'm trying to get:

```r
Prestige$type<-factor(Prestige$type, levels=c("bc","wc","prof")
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem or what I'm doing wrong and any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: Could you explain the line `Prestige <- na.omit`?

Comment: `Prestige<-na.omit` overwrites the value of the variable with a *function*. If you want to remove `NA`s from the data, you need to do `Prestige <- na.omit(Prestige)` *before reassigning it* (to a function). It's similar to doing `Prestige <- 1` and wondering why it is no longer the original variable/value.

Comment: It looks like you've made Prestige into the function `na.omit` instead of (I presume) omitting NAs from it.

Comment: In general, 'closure' refers to function and if you see that error it usually means you're trying to do something to a function when you want to do it to your data.